# How can prevent loading Dashboard on clicking browser's back button after login out of the application?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

I am working in ASP.Net with MVC5. Once when i sign out of the application and click the Back button of browser i am redirecting back to the page where i was sighned in.
I tried to clear the session but still the problem exists

anyone is there who can help me with MVC 5 caching....plss

I am thinking about using Redis for caching but no idea how to implement

Comment: Have you tried with FormsAuthentication.Signout() ?

Comment: @gkrishy no. I am not

Comment: @gkrishy how can we configure the application to use formsauthentication?

Comment: Have you created any controller page for logout ?. If so, use this formsauthentication.signout() in Index() Method.

Comment: @gkrishy after signout its going to index page with the following code ` #region LogOut [CustomActionFilter] [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] public ActionResult UserLogOut() { new UserControllerHelper().ExpireCookie(); if (Request.Url != null) { string url = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped); FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); return Redirect(url); } return null; } #endregion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to disable output (browser) caching so that the browser doesn't store a copy of your "secured" page after the user logs out. Currently the browser stores a cached copy of the page locally, since the browser has no concept of "logged in" or not, it just displays the page - the request never hits your MVC Controller because the browser says "hey, i have that page already, here it is!"

You can disable it on every "Authorize" action/controller using the following attribute

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] // will be applied to all actions in MyController, unless those actions override with their own decoration
public class MyController : Controller
{
  // ... 
}
```

or you can disable it globally by using the following in your FilterConfig.cs class.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute
                    {
                        VaryByParam = "*",
                        Duration = 0,
                        NoStore = true,
                    });
    // the rest of your global filters here
}
```

Comment: yes that worked for me :) thank you
i put `[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]` and it stopped caching the page history so not going to that page in clicking back :)